# Can a website be cached anywhere other than a browser's cache?

Tags: browser-cache

My client is seeing a different version of the website on his computers then what I am seeing on mine. He claims to be deleting the cache. I'm using Safari with the cache disabled via the Develop menu and I see the correct version of the site.

Is it possible that the website is somehow cached by my client's ISP or something along those lines?

***Update:***

I think I need to describe the problem better:

My client has a web hosting package where he has his domains and email accounts. somedomain.com has it's A record changed to point to Behance's ProSite hosted service.

The problem is that when he goes to somedomain.com he gets the index.html that's sitting in his web server's public_html directory, and not his ProSite. Using the same domain I see the ProSite. He has cleared his cache and tried on a computer at home with the same result. This is what lead me to believe that there is some sort of caching issue somewhere along the line with his ISP(s).

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 2):

Proxy servers at the ISP or even the client's site might do this.  Or even network-compressors in some (mal)configurations.

Depending on the site you might also be seeing actually a different site.  e.g. Google redirects to different servers using DNS load balancing.

Comment: Use the "Cache-Control" and "Expires" HTTP response headers to try and keep intermediate nodes from caching your content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. To improve performance and the speed in loading page from the same request modern browser seem to great at caching. I myself have the same problem as well. To resolve this problem You should tag version of your projects whenever you deploy them to production.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the update, the problem was with DNS cache.

DNS can be cached at the following levels:

- browser
- operation system
- router
- DNS provider

And each of them has its own way to flush DNS cache. Except DNS provider where the only thing you can is to wait for cache invalidation. Though you can replace your current DNS provider with another one who won't have your domain in his cache. You have all the chances to find such if your domain isn't popular.